# UCM - How to access repeat children nodes from XML

Tags: idocscript

I've got an XML document -

```
<PARTNER>
 <CompanyName>ABCD<CompanyName>
 <Address>XYZ</Address>
 <OFFER>
  <OFFERNAME>ABCDEFG</OFFERNAME>
  <OFFERDESC>XYZWV</OFFERDESC>
 </OFFER>
 <OFFER>
  <OFFERNAME>123456</OFFERNAME>
  <OFFERDESC>98765</OFFERDESC>
 </OFFER>
</PARTNER>
```

I want to access the individual OFFERNAME, OFFERDESC elements from each of the OFFER
tags.

`<!--$ssIncludeXml("dDocName","wcm:root/wcm:element[@name="OFFER"]/node()")-->`

Gives me the entire ABCDEFG XYZWV 123456 98765 which I do not want. Is there a
way I can access OFFERNAME, OFFERDESC from each of the OFFER tags?

PS: I have 2 OFFER nodes and each of them has 17 children nodes. When I try

`<!--$ssGetXmlNodeCount("dDocName", "wcm:root/wcm:element[@name='OFFER']/node()")-->`, I
get 34.

`<!--$ssIncludeXml("dDocName","wcm:root/wcm:element[@name="OFFER"][1]/node()")-->` prints
nothing.

Comment: Got the answer. It has to be <!--$ssIncludeXml("dDocName","PARTNER/OFFER[1]/OFFERNAME/text()")-->